# Connectedness of moduli spaces of semistable sheaves on K3

Tags: coherent-sheaves

In 1987/88, Mukai described the moduli spaces of (semi-)stable sheaves on a K3 surface $X$, showing that they consist of smooth pieces $M(v)$ of dimension $\langle v , v \rangle + 2$, for every primitive vector $v$ in the integral cohomology Mukai lattice which satisfies $\langle v , v \rangle \geq -2$, where $\langle v,w\rangle \,:=\, \int_X v^{\mathrm{rev}} \cup w$ (this $v$ then being the normalized Chern character of the sheaves in this component):

- S. Mukai: *Moduli spaces of vector bundles on K3 surfaces and symplectic manifolds*,
  Sugaku Expositions **1** 2 (1988) ([pdf](https://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/%7Emukai/paper/Sugaku_1987.pdf))

This kind of statement has meanwhile been generalized to stability with respect to any "generic full numerical" Bridgeland stability conditions on K3. One place where the state of the art as of 8 years ago is succinctly reviewed and referenced is around [Thm. 2.15](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.6968.pdf#page=12) of:

- A. Bayer and E. Macri, *MMP for moduli of sheaves on K3s via wall-crossing: nef and movable cones, Lagrangian fibrations*, Inv. math. **198** (2014) 505–590
  ([doi:10.1007/s00222-014-0501-8](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00222-014-0501-8), [arXiv:1301.6968](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.6968))

But Mukai had one more observation, namely the **conjecture that each $M(v)$ is connected** ([p. 19](https://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/%7Emukai/paper/Sugaku_1987.pdf#page=19)).

Is there anything known, meanwhile, about whether or when Mukai's conjecture holds?

If it fails, is there any idea about the number of connected components of each $M(v)$ (either in general or for specific cases)?